# New Feature Lambda Overloading in Java

Tags: java, lambda, overloading

I'm a little bit confused about why there is no such thing like lambda overloading.
I know lambda expression work with `@FunctionalInterface` If you have two or more abstract method in interface then compiler can't decide what function to call when you are using a lambda expression, so it is necessary to have only one abstract method in the interface if you want to use a lambda expression. But what if you have two or more function with different arguments or a different type of arguments or return type than the compiler can easily decide what function to call.

For example:

```
 interface Foo{
     void show(String message);
     void count(int number);
 }

 // Calling with lambda (Syntax is not correct)
 x -> "Example Message";  // It should need to call void show();
 x -> 7; // It should need to call void count();
```

Why this kind of thing is not available in java. isn't it a good thing.

Comment: What would you expect `x -> "Example Message"` to perform then if I also add `void hide(String message)` to the existing interface? to `show` or to `hide`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've considered one side of the problem - which method the lambda expression should correspond to. What you haven't considered is what happens to all *other* methods in the interface.

The language *could* be specified so that the lambda expression corresponds to one method, and all the others throw a `RuntimeException` - but that would rarely be useful. Consider how the `Foo` would be *used*. You'd end up with an object that you could only call some methods on, and you wouldn't even know *which* methods you could call safely.

If you know you're only going to call one method (e.g. `count` in your example), then that's one standalone piece of functionality, and can be encapsulated in an interface on its own - at which point existing lambda expression functionality is fine. If you *don't* know that you only want to use a single method, then your proposal won't help anyway.